# How does one display the value of an object on a graph/plot (in matplotlib)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to be able to display an object; call it "Slope", on my matplotlib graph. Eg:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

range1 = a[(-5. <= a) & (-3. >= a)]
range2 = b[(-5. <= a) & (-3. >= a)]

'''Calculate slope value from endpoints in the data range (linear).'''

xslopeentry1 = range1[0]
xslopeentry2 = range1[-1]
yslopeentry1 = range2[0]
yslopeentry2 = range2[-1]
Slope = (yslopeentry2-yslopeentry1)/(xslopeentry2-xslopeentry1)

plt.plot(range1,range2)
plt.show()
```

Now, how will I be able to 'print', or display the value obtained for 'Slope' on my plot?

Answer (score 3):

There are several options for adding text in matplotlib. The best explanation of them comes from the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html).

For your purpose, there are 3 options that may make sense:

1.) [Text relative to axes](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text):

```
matplotlib.pyplot.text(Slope,x,y)
```

where x and y are the coordinates of the text relative to the axes.

2.) [Text relative to figure](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figtext):

```
matplotlib.pyplot.figtext(Slope,x,y)
```

where x and y are the coordinates of the text relative to the figure

3.) [Annotation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate):

This creates a piece text annotation referring to a specific data point. This doesn't make as much sense here, but it does allow for easy arrow creation, if you wanted an arrow pointing to the line the slope related to.

```
matplotlib.pyplot.annotate(Slope, xy=(xx, yy), xytext=(x, y),
        arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05))
```

where x and y are the text coordinates, and xx, yy are the coordinates of the point the arrow points to.

**Note that the examples above only place the value of the slope on the plot. If you want "Slope: value" instead, replace "Slope" above with:

```
"Slope: {0}".format(Slope)
```